# How to pass unnamed string array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

Suppose I want to pass **string array** as an argument in my javascript function `myFun()` as follows:

```
myFun({"Hello","Sam","Good Morning"});
```

But this does not work, neither does:

```
myFun(["Hello","Sam","Good Morning"]);
```

Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem here? or at least share the code

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: post the error pls

Comment: your second line of code _should_ work - it's completely legal.  You need to explain why exactly you think it doesn't work, show any error that might be generated, and probably include the `myFun` function, too.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are trying to do?

```
function myFunc(namearray) {
      return "Success";
};

console.log(myFunc(["Hello", "Sam", "Good Morning"]));
```

Comment: What kind of question, this type of response)

Answer (score -1):

Do not receive the array as you are passing. Do this

```
var textArr = ["Hello","Sam","Good Morning"];
myFunction(textArr);

function myFunction(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to declare it, I simply want to pass it , like you pass an integer without declaring it.

Comment: I am not getting your point. Why don't you want to declare it. If you write the complete array in myFunction(["val1", "val2", "val3"]) then why its not better to have it declared before.

Comment: There is _nothing wrong whatsoever_ with the second code example the OP showed.  Moving the array into a variable does not address his problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can user below code to pass a string array to a function without declaring it :

```js
function foo(obj) {
  alert(obj.strArray[0]);
}

foo({
  strArray: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
});
```

Comment: Why down voted this answer? Probably could have suggested some other or improved way.

Answer (score -1):

Well you might even do some destructuring fanciness.

```js
var destruct = ([obj,num,str]) => console.log(obj,num,str)
destruct([{name: "Rondinelli", age:3}, 42, "Brontosaurus"]);
```

And here we have a string only version which might address the OP's question more directly.

```js
var destruct = ([s1,s2,s3]) => console.log(s1,s2,s3)
destruct(["Rondinelli", "Plexy_Something", "Brontosaurus"]);
```

Comment: this does not address the OP's problem with passing a (perfectly legal) string array literal

Comment: @Alnitak While OP's question is not very clear, in my answer i demonstrate the array destructuring as a way of parameter passing. I showed it with a variety of types. Well OK let me add a string only version.